# selenium (python) webdriver JavaScript (noscrypt)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, scrape

I am trying to scraping data from a site provide note of student to make analysis
I try this good

```
from selenium import webdriver
#set chromodriver.exe path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
#set page load timeout

#launch URL
driver.get("https://amatti.education.gov.dz/")
```

the first thing happen when run this code is open the site :
[the site open normal][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay7QJ.png
after the site open it go to this site :

[after open go to this site][2]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWvEa.png

I notice there is this good in the html of the site
that mean if the browser not support JavaScript will go to URL : google.com

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.google.com/" />
</noscript>
```

there is any solution to automate this site
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay7QJ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWvEa.png

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
the problem comes from WebDrive
the site knows there is bot scraping data
so i use this argument

```
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
```

and its work fine